# Timer keeps looping

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I got this timer (timer2) and it runs every 60 seconds..
And I got this second timer (timer4)

when 60 seconds are over, the timer2_Tick does a few things and initiates timer4.
timer 4 makes sure to wait 4 seconds before coming  in action (I need 4 seconds to be sure that all the downloaded data is there)

when these 4 seconds are over the timer should change an image and it does..
So it all works..

The problem is that every 4 seconds the image blinks.. the image is inside an datta template..

how do I stop that..?? do i need the Stop() or do I need an running counter..??

please help this is driving me nuts..

```
    private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        locationTextBox2.Text = "";

        if (locationTextBox2.Text == "")
        {
            Weatherframe.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("");
        }

        Weatherframe2.Source = Weatherframe.Source; 

        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer4 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        timer4.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4, 000); // 500 Milliseconds
        timer4.Tick += new EventHandler(timer4_Tick);
        timer4.Start();

    }

    void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (locationTextBox2.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            locationTextBox2.Text = textBlock2.Text;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never stop the timer, so it will keep ticking every fourth second.

Just call `Stop` on the timer in the handler, but for that you need to keep the reference to the timer in a member variable so that you can access it after you created it.

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer timer4;

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    locationTextBox2.Text = "";

    if (locationTextBox2.Text == "")
    {
        Weatherframe.Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("");
    }

    Weatherframe2.Source = Weatherframe.Source; 

    timer 4 = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    timer4.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 4, 000); // 500 Milliseconds
    timer4.Tick += new EventHandler(timer4_Tick);
    timer4.Start();

}

void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer4.Stop();
    if (locationTextBox2.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        locationTextBox2.Text = textBlock2.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.. but I already tried placing timer4.Stop() inside de handler but it didn't work.. I guess thats where the reference comes in.. I dont know how to do that..

Comment: @youngblade: Declare the variable outside the method so that it's a member of the class instead.

Comment: I understand but don't knowhow to do it.. kinda of an beginner.. could you show me how.. I tried: int timer4; timer4.Stop()

Comment: @youngblade: Declaring a new variable with the same name doesn't get you access to the first variable. You have to use the same variable in both methods. I added code above.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably listen to when the image has actually been downloaded rather than guess that it takes 4 seconds. You can do that by subscribing to the DownloadCompleted event on BitmapSource

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.downloadcompleted.aspx

You should probably also listen for DownloadFailed and DecodeFailed to detect errors.

Comment: Its not the image thats being downloaded.. Its first the Geographicle data (latitude and longitude) and after that some weather data and depending on the weather condition I set some images.. the images are localy stored in the app..

Comment: You should still watch for the completion of download rather than guessing a fixed time. Webclient.DownloaddataCompleted or even better look into Task Parallel Library and then do a Task.WhenAll(tasks, ()=>OnAllDownloaded);

Answer (score 0):

```
void timer4_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (locationTextBox2.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        locationTextBox2.Text = textBlock2.Text;
        System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer theTimer = sender as System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer;
        theTimer.Stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ow I didnt see yor reply until now.. I'll go and try it out right away..!!

Comment: Error 1 The type or namespace name 'Timer' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) I think we need a refference?? I'm not sure..